# Python: 'before' and 'after' for multiprocessing workers

Tags: python, multiprocessing, generator

**Update**: Here is a more specific example

Suppose I want to compile some statistical data from a sizable set of files: 
I can make a generator `(line for line in fileinput.input(files))` and some processor:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
scores = defaultdict(int) 

def process(line): 
    if 'Result' in line: 
        res = line.split('\"')[1].split('-')[0]
        scores[res] += 1
```

The question is how to handle this when one gets to the `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Of course it's possible to define a `multiprocessing.sharedctypes` as well as a custom `struct` instead of a `defaultdict` but this seems rather painful. On the other hand I can't think of a pythonic way to instantiate something before the process or to return something after a generator has run out to the main thread.

Comment: maybe someone else understands what your question is... but I dont think I do.  could you clarify further?

Comment: Did you understand what the `else` clause does in a for loop?

Comment: What problem are you solving for?  Do you want to know when each item is finished?  When they are all finished?  Something else?

Comment: What is the first bit of code doing?  Usually `else` after a `for` clause denotes a construct that means "if the loop didn't encounter a break statement, do this", but with just `process(i)` I'm not sure what you expect the `else` to do here.

Comment: Let me make the question more specific, sorry folks

Comment: `def f(): print "'finished'"`, followed by `[f() for _ in xrange(4)]` does what you described :).

Comment: @JoranBeasley Maybe this is better, idk, I was trying to think of a clever way to pass data back to the main process after a generator had run out without the processes actually working in shared memory.

Comment: @user3467349 thats what pipes are for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically create a histogram. This is can easily be parallelized, because histograms can be merged without complication. One might want to say that this problem is trivially parallelizable or ["embarrassingly parallel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). That is, you do not need to worry about communication among workers.

Just split your data set into multiple chunks, let your workers work on these chunks **independently**, collect the histogram of each worker, and then merge the histograms.

In practice, this problem is best off by letting each worker process/read its own file. That is, a "task" could be a file name. You should not start pickling file contents and send them around between processes through pipes. Let each worker process retrieve the bulk data *directly* from files. Otherwise your architecture spends too much time with inter-process communication, instead of doing some real work.

Do you need an example or can you figure this out yourself?

### Edit: example implementation

I have a number of data files with file names in this format: `data0.txt`, `data1.txt`, ... .

Example contents:

```
wolf
wolf
cat
blume
eisenbahn
```

The goal is to create a histogram over the words contained in the data files. This is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import Counter
import glob


def build_histogram(filepath):
    """This function is run by a worker process.
    The `filepath` argument is communicated to the worker
    through a pipe. The return value of this function is
    communicated to the manager through a pipe.
    """
    hist = Counter()
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            hist[line.strip()] += 1
    return hist


def main():
    """This function runs in the manager (main) process."""

    # Collect paths to data files.
    datafile_paths = glob.glob("data*.txt")

    # Create a pool of worker processes and distribute work.
    # The input to worker processes (function argument) as well
    # as the output by worker processes is transmitted through
    # pipes, behind the scenes.
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    histograms = pool.map(build_histogram, datafile_paths)

    # Properly shut down the pool of worker processes, and
    # wait until all of them have finished.
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Merge sub-histograms. Do not create too many intermediate
    # objects: update the first sub-histogram with the others.
    # Relevant docs: collections.Counter.update
    merged_hist = histograms[0]
    for h in histograms[1:]:
        merged_hist.update(h)

    for word, count in merged_hist.items():
        print "%s: %s" % (word, count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Test output:

```
python countwords.py
eisenbahn: 12
auto: 6
cat: 1
katze: 10
stadt: 1
wolf: 3
zug: 4
blume: 5
herbert: 14
destruction: 4
```

Comment: Yes its trivial to do in this case because you know you can split the data prior to iteration but that doesn't make it any better in the general case. i.e. if `fileinput.input` was a single socket object.

Comment: You were asking "The question is how to handle this when one gets to the multiprocessing.Pool." --- there, the most important question is the "parallel" nature of the problem and to which degree it is decomposable into tasks. Not every generator-based solution can be translated into a standard mp Pool recipe!

Comment: My question was how to call before and after functions for a generator when `pool.map` is called -it wasn't help me `islice` the list of files, although of course that works in this case, and maybe my example was not so good.

Comment: I think everybody is wondering: what are the "before" and "after" functions for a generator? You really need to be more explicit with your wording... :)

Comment: I know, I think I just suck at asking specific questions - i.e. to __init__ a counter within the process memory that is spawned by pool before iteration and then to return the value of that counter after the generator is empty.

Comment: Good. My answer fits :-). I was suggesting that you build a histogram in each worker process exactly the way you did it in your example. That is, you create a `scores = defaultdict(int)` in every worker process. These instances do not see each other, the workers work absolutely independently, no shared memory involved. After a worker process has processed all of his input data, it pickles `scores`  and sends it through a pipe or queue to the manager process. The manager receives it, unpickles it, and stores it. This way, the manager collects all histograms and merges them into the final one.

Comment: You're right of course , only I was hoping there would be something nice and very quick like `else return scores` when the generator is empty.

Comment: I have brought an example implementation for you. Will update my answer in a minute.

Comment: I just realized pool.map cannot be called with a generator at all, so that makes my whole question rather moot, for some reason I was under the impression that it could be.

Comment: The `iterable` argument to `map()` can very well be a real iterator (as is returned by calling a generator). In my example, `pool.map(build_histogram, iter(datafile_paths))` would work, for instance.

Comment: `pool.map(build_histogram, (f for f in datafile_paths))` also works, of course.

Comment: Really did you run it? It not only specifically doesn't work - but looking at the source of `pool.py` it's obvious it should never work because pool.map uses `len(iterable)`. `imap` might do it though.

Comment: I tried, it works. At which source did you look? In Python 2.7 as well as 3.4 the iterable is expanded to a list if `__len__` is not available: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L304  and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L343

Comment: You're right, I didn't look carefully, I'm going to blame this on some kind of weird ipython thing because I actually could not run it with an iterator, at any rate since it expands to a list `map` probably shouldn't be used if you really don't know the data len (or on large sets).

Comment: Right, you should know the amount of data, at least roughly (the order of magnitude, so to say). But this has nothing to do with whether you use a generator or not. So, no, you shouldn't use this as an argument not to use a generator. In other words: nobody will ever write something like this: `if len(l) > N: raise Exception("Too large, abort!")`. Agreed? So, go ahead and use generators, because they often are just more elegant :-).

Comment: `Imap` won't evaluate the generator to a list, so it will actually run faster than `map` with chunks will for cases with alot of input. Also I'm trying to use the `initializer` argument to send an init method to workers, and it invariably produces errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the original pool.py (the trouble was worker is defined as a method without any inheritance) to get what I want but it's not so bad, and probably better than writing a new pool entirely.

```
class worker(object):
    def __init__(self, inqueue, outqueue, initializer=None, initargs=(), maxtasks=None,
           wrap_exception=False, finalizer=None, finargs=()): 
        assert maxtasks is None or (type(maxtasks) == int and maxtasks > 0)
        put = outqueue.put
        get = inqueue.get
        self.completed = 0
        if hasattr(inqueue, '_writer'):
            inqueue._writer.close()
            outqueue._reader.close()
        if initializer is not None:
            initializer(self, *initargs)

        def run(self): 
            while maxtasks is None or (maxtasks and self.completed < maxtasks):
                try:
                    task = get()
                except (EOFError, OSError):
                    util.debug('worker got EOFError or OSError -- exiting')
                    break

                if task is None:
                    util.debug('worker got sentinel -- exiting')
                    break

                job, i, func, args, kwds = task
                try:
                    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
                except Exception as e:
                    if wrap_exception:
                        e = ExceptionWithTraceback(e, e.__traceback__)
                    result = (False, e)
                try:
                    put((job, i, result))
                except Exception as e:
                    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
                    util.debug("Possible encoding error while sending result: %s" % (
                        wrapped))
                    put((job, i, (False, wrapped)))
                self.completed += 1
            if finalizer:
                finalizer(self, *finargs)
            util.debug('worker exiting after %d tasks' % self.completed)
        run(self)
```