# python multiprocessing shared Counter , pickling error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I am multiprocessing to process some very large files.

I can count occurrences of a particular string  using the collections.Counter collection that is shared between the processes using a multiprocessing.BaseManager subclass.

Although I can share the Counter and seemingly pickle it does not seem to be pickled properly. I can copy the dictionary to a new dictionary that I can pickle.

I am trying to understand how to avoid the "copy" of the shared counter before picking it.

Here is my (pseudocode):

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from collections import Counter

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('Counter', Counter)

def main(glob_pattern):
    # function that processes files
    def worker_process(files_split_to_allow_naive_parallelization, mycounterdict):
        # code that loops through files
        for line in file:
            # code that processes line
            my_line_items = line.split()
            index_for_read = (my_line_items[0],my_line_items[6])
            mycounterdict.update((index_for_read,))

    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    mycounterdict = manager.Counter()

    # code to get glob files , split them with unix shell split and then chunk then

    for i in range(NUM_PROCS):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process , args = (all_index_file_tuples[chunksize * i:chunksize * (i + 1)],mycounterdict))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()
    # Now we "join" the processes
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    # This is the part I have trouble with
    # This yields a pickled file that fails with an error
    pickle.dump(mycounterdict,open("Combined_count_gives_error.p","wb"))

    # This however works
    # How can I avoid doing it this way?
    mycopydict = Counter()
    mydictcopy.update(mycounterdict.items())
    pickle.dump(mycopydict,open("Combined_count_that_works.p","wb"))
```

When I try to load the "pickled" error giving file which is always a smaller fixed size , I get an error that does not make sense.

How do I pickle the shared dict without going through the creation of fresh dict in the pseudocode above.

```
>>> p = pickle.load(open("Combined_count_gives_error.p"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code: `mycounterdict.update((index_for_read,)`.

Comment: Your approach is complex. I wouldn't use a shared Counter object, because the communication and synchronization overhead may actually limit the file I/O performance of single worker processes. Alternative approach: let single workers each process one file (or file part) on their own (do not send the raw data to them, let them *read the data from the file system*), let each worker create a Counter object, send all "sub" Counter objects to your main process (via Queue or Pipe), and merge them. In fact, I have recently provided a working example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28097807/145400

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke approach is the one you should persue - never try to have a global state whenever you are doing multiprocessing - keep shared data immutable to each thread. To add to Jan's suggestion I would suggest you run all subprocesses first, and then let your main thread merge it all together in the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code. First of all, you are not guaranteed to close the file if you leave it dangling. Secondly, the `mycounterdict` is not an actual `Counter` but a proxy over it - pickle it and you will run into many problems, as it is unpicklable outside this process. However, you do not need to copy with `update` either: `.copy` makes a new `Counter` copy of it.

Thus you should use

```
with open("out.p", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(mycounterdict.copy(), f)
```

As for if this is a good pattern, the answer is **no**. Instead of using a shared counter you should count separately in each process, for a much simpler code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import Counter
import pickle

def calculate(file):
    counts = Counter()
    ...
    return counts

pool = Pool(processes=NPROCS)
counts = Counter()
for result in pool.map(calculate, files):
    counts += result

with open("out.p", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(counts, f)
```

Comment: I like your answer, and that it really is the same approach that I linked to already in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28097807/145400 ;-).